# OpenCVのcloneについて

Tags: c++, opencv, マルチスレッド

OpenCVとアナログカメラを使用したプログラムを作成している際に「アクセス違反」のエラーが発生してしまいます．
マルチスレッドでプログラミングをしており，1つ目のスレッドでカメラから取得した画像をcv::Matに変換しています．この画像を2つ目のスレッドで画像処理を行おうとしています．

<画像を取得しているスレッド>

```
cv::Mat frame;
DWORD WINAPI ImageThread(LPVOID lpData)
{   
    while (!lpd->bEnd){

        if (mJpegData != nullptr&&mJpegSize > 0) {
            std::vector<unsigned char> tmp(mJpegData, mJpegData + mJpegSize);
            frame = cv::imdecode(tmp, cv::IMREAD_COLOR);
            cv::imwrite("img_debug.bmp", frame);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

<画像をコピーしているスレッド>

```
DWORD WINAPI ConThread(LPVOID lpData)
{
    cv::Mat img;

    while (!lpd->bEnd){
        if (!frame.empty) {
            img = frame.clone();  //ここをコメントアウトするとエラーは発生しない
        }
    }
}
```

OpenCVのバージョンは3.3を使用しております．
どなたか解決法を教えていただけないでしょうか．

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> frame = cv::imdecode(tmp, cv::IMREAD_COLOR);
> ```

この行で[cv::Mat::operator=()](https://docs.opencv.org/3.3.0/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#aed1f81fe7efaacc2bd95149cdfa34302)が呼ばれます。

> Before assigning new data, the old data is de-referenced via Mat::release.

と説明されている通り、`frame`の保持していたデータは解放されます。別スレッドで`frame.clone()`により読み出していればエラーになるのも当然です。

排他処理を挿入することで解決できますが、ロック範囲をどうするか、また`frame`変数以外にも排他すべき項目がないか、検討することをお勧めします。

<画像を取得しているスレッド>

```
cv::Mat frame;
cv::Mutex mutex;
DWORD WINAPI ImageThread(LPVOID lpData)
{   
    while (!lpd->bEnd){

        if (mJpegData != nullptr&&mJpegSize > 0) {
            std::vector<unsigned char> tmp(mJpegData, mJpegData + mJpegSize);
            cv::AutoLock lock(mutex);
            frame = cv::imdecode(tmp, cv::IMREAD_COLOR);
            cv::imwrite("img_debug.bmp", frame);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

<画像をコピーしているスレッド>

```
DWORD WINAPI ConThread(LPVOID lpData)
{
    cv::Mat img;

    while (!lpd->bEnd){
        cv::AutoLock lock(mutex);
        if (!frame.empty) {
            img = frame.clone();
        }
    }
}
```

---

> 画像をコピーしているスレッドで「if(!frame.empty())」を行っているのですが，このif文と「img=frame.clone()」の間でframeに定義されない（不定の）タイミングが発生する可能性がある（発生してしまった）ためにエラーが出てしまうという認識でよろしいでしょうか．

「間」のみならず`frame.clone()`実行中でも、別スレッドで`Mat::release`によりメモリ解放されてしまえばアクセス違反が発生します。C++言語ではオブジェクトがGC管理されているわけではないので、他言語によくある「実行中だから解放されない」といった保証はありません。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。画像をコピーしているスレッドで「if(!frame.empty())」を行っているのですが，このif文と「img=frame.clone()」の間でframeに定義されない（不定の）タイミングが発生する可能性がある（発生してしまった）ためにエラーが出てしまうという認識でよろしいでしょうか．

Comment: @Rlia さん回答へ加筆しました。